# Using Web Audio API to add silence to beginning of sound

Tags: javascript, audio, web, html5-audio

I found out that it's possible to create audio buffers with Javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer). I'm still not sure what this API does, but I'd like to know whether there is there a way to add `x` seconds of silence in front of an `.ogg` file and play it in the browser?

Edit:

The purpose is to create a timer that works on mobile browsers even for long timeouts. If the phone goes to sleep `SetTimeout` and `SetInterval` will stop (as well as other JavaScript code). My workaround would be to create a sound file which contains i.e. 40min of silence and then plays the alarm bell (the sound keeps playing in the background even though JavaScript is not executing anymore in background tabs). But creating such files is not very flexible and costs traffic. I thought of using this API to accomplish what I've described without creating a file with silence + bell offline.

Comment: @Kaiido I've updated the question and added a description

Comment: I would suggest learning more about JavaScript and how it works on mobile browsers, and do more research on the Web Audio API. The question as it stands sounds like you're asking the volunteers on SO to write a lot of code for you...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Before I decide to go into the Web API, I only wanted to know if it is possible to do what I wanted. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a site where ["is it possible" questions go over well](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270933/215552). The answer is almost always "try it and see". If you change the question to be "How do I", which apparently I did unconsciously, then you can see how it's far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this also solves your problem. I archived this behavior in another way. I just waited x seconds before playing the sound.

My Code looks like

```
var audio = new Audio('sound.mp3');

function start() {
    audio.play();
}

setTimeout(start, 2000);
```

Instead of 2000 you can use x and multiply it with 1000.

Does it work for you or is there a point that I'm missing?

Comment: Given the current *un-clarity* of the  question, I'd say this is a clever solution ;-)

Comment: The problem is this will not work on mobile phones when they are in sleep. I've maybe been not very precise in the question. Going to edit it.